# Can I submit commits to someone else's pull request in my repository?

Tags: github

Someone has issued a pull request into my code, and I have a few changes I'd like to make rather than rejecting the request or waiting for them to make them.

I have no idea what the etiquette is, but I'd like to know if I can submit commits into the pull request directly without merging it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On GitHub, the person who submitted the pull request has the option to allow updates from maintainers. If that is enabled (by default), you will be able to commit to the forked repository (and this change the contents of the pull request).

I would not consider this a violation of etiquette (since they allow you to commit changes), and it's more useful since you can merge the correct code into your repostory/branch.

The official documentation for this feature can be found at https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/ and https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/.

[image: github screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way I can tell if this setting is on for a pull request?

Comment: I'm not sure you can see it. You can of course try to push to the pull request branch. The official docs are at https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/ .

Answer (score 0):

Afaik pull requests are branches which want to merge into `master`, so committing to a branch seems possible as long as you have write permissions on it. Github should tell you, if you are able to write to that branch.